# Store data in array after split

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I retrieve from my servlet the following data and i would like to store these data `["-1.2396853,52.7680791","-1.2396572,52.7682574","-1.2396083,52.7684203"]` in the coords like below.

for example coords should be presented: `var coords = [[-1.2396853, 52.7680791],[-1.2396572, 52.7682574],[-1.2396083, 52.7684203]];`

```
$.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: "servlet",
 success: function(data) { 
  var coordinates = JSON.parse(data).toString();
  var coords = [];
  var coords = coordinates.split(",");
}
});
```

any suggestion how i can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So given:

```
var o = ["-1.2396853,52.7680791","-1.2396572,52.7682574","-1.2396083,52.7684203"];
```

You can convert it to your result like this:

```
var result = o.map(function(i) {
    var cells = i.split(",");
    return [+cells[0],+cells[1]];
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HtaU4/

Note: you might want to include some error checking to check that the split does give you a pair of values.

Comment: does this solution convert the strings to numbers?

Comment: @Panagiotis: Yes. Try it and see.

Answer (score 0):

Your success function should look like

```
var coordinates = JSON.parse(data);
var coords = [];

for (var i=0, c; c = coordinates[i]; i++) {
  coords.push(c.split(","));
}
```

Comment: `c = coordinates[i]`? That's an interesting trick for a loop condition. Seems a lot less readable that just checking `.length`

Comment: Thanks a lot James. That works perfectly. Can you please explain me a little bit this part "c; c = coordinates[i];" of for loop?

Comment: Also, this doesn't convert the answer to a number. It's still a string.

Comment: @Panagiotis: Because `coordinates[i]` will return `undefined` for an index that doesn't exist, which is falsy. So when you get beyond the end of the array, `coordinates[i]` will evaluate as false and the loop will end. Why James didn't just compare `i` with `length` is beyond me. I've never seen anybody do that before. It's kind of a poor mans `foreach` loop.

Comment: @MattBurland true it's less readable, and prone to fail if coordinates[k] is falsy.  If you plan on using `c` though it makes your code a lot more compact.

Comment: Thanks a lot Matt for your explanation.